# How to write multiple conditions using IF in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, data-science

I am trying to test whether the subject ID tested in an application is classified (ADHD-combined, ADHD-inattentive or healthy) correctly or not.
I have a table with identifier names and the decision in percentages.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| subject_id | decision |
| NDARAA112DMH | 0.55196626 |
| NDARAD615WLJ | 0.58124495 |
| NDARAG143ARJ | 0.65364915 |

I want to have a table like this after I use the "IF" formula in excel.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| subject_id | decision | result |
| NDARAA112DMH | 0.55196626 | combined |
| NDARAD615WLJ | 0.58124495 | inattentive |
| NDARAG143ARJ | 0.65364915 | inattentive |

How to write this expression in an excel formula
if B2 = 0.55±0.02 then write "combined"
if B2 = 0.59 ± 0.09 then write "inattentive"
else write "healthy".
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The conditions as stated are ambiguous: if `B2=0.56` then that meets the conditions for `combined` and for `inattentive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(ABS(B2-0.55)<0.02,"combined",IF(ABS(B2-0.59)<0.09,"inattentive","healthy"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried using the formula, but I get a prompt that - "There is a problem with this formula".

Comment: @Sanyukta When I copy the formula above and paste it into Excel and it works for me, so I don't know what the problem could be.